# Pressure (S)ARIMA(X) models towards target

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to forecast time-series in a very "applied" sense.
Ideally, what I would be looking for was a time-series model (à la ARIMA models), which could capture the dynamics of the growth data of an index. However, I have strong a priori ideas about how to series will/should behave over the long term (justified or not).

Therefore, I would like to be able to specify a long-run trend, or a long run equilibirum for the series (on a monthly, quarterly or yearly basis), yet still capture the seasonality via an ARIMA-type model. Does anyone know any ways/models to do such a thing?

Comment: What do you think about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the deviation from the equilibrium as a new regressor and use it as an exogenous regressor in an ARIMAX model or a regression with ARMA errors. E.g. if you are interested in forecasting $y$ and know that in equilibrium $y\approx \beta x$, you could say
\begin{aligned}
\Delta y_t &= \alpha (y_{t-1} - \beta x_{t-1}) + u_t, \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + \dotsc + \varphi_p u_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \dotsc + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q}.
\end{aligned}
The second line gives an ARMA specification for the error term. You may replace it with SARIMA if needed, or keep it that way but add some seasonal dummies or Fourier terms in the first line instead.

Note that you could either estimate $\beta$ or fix it at some value implied by theory.

---

Alternatively, you could seasonally adjust $y_t$ first (using some SARIMA model, for example) and then model the relationship between the seasonally-adjusted $y_t$ and $x_t$.